# iOS enable kAudioUnitProperty_MeteringMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm trying to set the value of "AudioUnitSetProperty" but my status is always "-10879".

```
UInt32 meteringMode = 1;
OSStatus status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.componetInstance, kAudioUnitProperty_MeteringMode, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &meteringMode, sizeof(meteringMode));
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

I try:

```
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.componetInstance, kAudioUnitProperty_MeteringMode, kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer, 0, &meteringMode, sizeof(meteringMode));
```

and I try:

```
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.componetInstance, kAudioUnitProperty_MeteringMode, kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer, 1, &meteringMode, sizeof(meteringMode));
```

the error remained.

Comment: kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer is used when creating the audio unit rather than when setting the property.

Answer (score 1):

This property is only valid for the multichannel mixer.  kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. I updated my question.